# Changing text of labels defined in a loop

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label, counter

I'm trying to make a scalable counter.

In the first window you enter how many counters you want.

In the second window there are labels and buttons used to add one to the label.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def newWindow():
    window = Toplevel()
    for i in range(int(textbox.get())):
        exec("global label"+ str(i))
        exec("label" + str(i) + " = Label(window, text = '0')")
        exec("label" + str(i) + ".grid(row = 0, column = i)")
        exec("global button"+ str(i))
        exec("button" + str(i) + " = Button(window, text = 'Add', command = lambda: setText(label" + str(i) + "))")
        exec("button" + str(i) + ".grid(row = 1, column = i)")

def setText(label):
    label.config(text = str(int(label.cget("text")) + 1))

textbox = Entry(root)
textbox.grid(row = 0)
submitButton = Button(root, text = "Submit", command = newWindow)
submitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

However this is the error I get:

```
name 'label_' is not defined
```

where _ is i.

Making them global didn't fix this either.

Help please!

Comment: Pleas show the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `exec` in this way, you're doing something very wrong.

The simple solution is to add widgets to a list or dictionary. Though, in this specific case you don't need that because you're never referencing the label anywhere but in the button command.

Here's a working example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def newWindow():
    global labels
    window = Toplevel()
    labels = {}
    for i in range(int(textbox.get())):
        label = Label(window, text='0')
        button = Button(window, text='Add', command = lambda l=label: setText(l))

        label.grid(row=0, column=i)
        button.grid(row=1, column=i)

        # this allows you to access any label later with something
        # like labels[3].configure(...)
        labels[i] = label

def setText(label):
    label.config(text = str(int(label.cget("text")) + 1))

textbox = Entry(root)
textbox.grid(row = 0)
submitButton = Button(root, text = "Submit", command = newWindow)
submitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

If you wanted to make use of `labels`, you could have your button pass in the index, and let `setText` get the widget from the dictionary:

```
def setText(i):
    label = labels[i]
    label.configure(...)
...
button = Button(..., command=lambda i=i: setText(i))
```